# How do I find one matching strings in two txt files

Tags: sql, file, comparison, substring, matching

I have to txt files with a bunch of data (in one case there is a string on each line that has an end of line break at the end in the other file its simply strings, with spaces but no distinct way to break apart the data). but sets of files consists of hyperlinks. This data doesn't currently exist in tables - I'm not sure of the best way to import it into appropriate columns/data fields).

all i need to do is pull the data "strings" that appear in both files.

Examples File1:

```
http://-28uw.c.cr http://www.2xik.com http://www.365cnblog.cn http://www.blogactif.net     http://www.blogactifs.com http://www.blogalbums.com http://www.blogallerys.com ... etc.
```

Example File2:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org
http://stayyoungafter50.com
http://108.160.146.227
http://10tv.com
http://110mb.com
```

I don't care about www or http or https all i want to do is find the matching 10tv.com in both files. or the cnn.com, that's it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: your question is vague so it's hard to give an answer with any value.

what I would suggest is write a little program in your language of choice, that reads through the 2 files. 
when it processes the 1st file - add the words to a dictionary object or equivalent. hopefully you can use logic like any white space will be considered a delimiter (new lines, spaces, tabs). you'd trim off things you don't care about like http:// and https:// etc when you store it.

then you read the 2nd file - checking if the (trimmed) words are in the dictionary. if they are, insert them into db.

Comment: as an additional note - I don't believe -28uw.c.cr is a valid host name. hostname labels should not start or end with a hyphen - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname.

Comment: @bkr thank you for your suggestions, the validity of the host names i am not responsible for these are the files I was provided. Ultimately I work with sql/databases so I was thinking of using soe form of sql to compare the data. but I'm not sure what is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it (though using PowerShell rather than SQL):

```
clear
pushd c:\myPath\myFolder\

#read in the contents of the files
$file1 = get-content("file1.txt") 
$file2 = get-content("file2.txt")

#loop through each row of the whitespace separated file
$file1 = $file1 | %{
    #for each line, split on whitespace characters, returning the results back in a single column
    $_ -split "\s" | %{$_}
}
#compare the two files for matching data & output this info
compare-object $file1 $file2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | ft -AutoSize 

popd
```

NB: to ignore the protocol, simply remove it from the string using a similar technique to our split on spaces; i.e. a regex, this time going with replace instead of split.

```
clear
pushd c:\temp

$file1 = get-content("file1.txt") 
$file2 = get-content("file2.txt")

$file1 = $file1 | %{
    $_ -split "\s" | %{
        $_ -replace ".*://(.*)",'$1'
    }
}

$file2 = $file2 | %{
    $_ -replace ".*://(.*)",'$1'
}

compare-object $file1 $file2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | ft -AutoSize
```

However, should you prefer a SQL solution, try this (MS SQL Server):

```
create table f1(url nvarchar(1024))
create table f2(url nvarchar(1024))

BULK INSERT f1
FROM 'C:\myPath\myFolder\file1.txt' 
WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR =' ', FIRSTROW = 1 )

BULK INSERT f2
FROM 'C:\myPath\myFolder\file2.txt' 
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 1 )
go

delete from f1 where coalesce(rtrim(url),'') = ''
delete from f2 where coalesce(rtrim(url),'') = ''

select x.url, x.x, y.y
from
(
    select SUBSTRING(url,patindex('%://%',url)+3, len(url)) x
    , url 
    from f1 
) x
inner join 
(
    select SUBSTRING(url,patindex('%://%',url)+3, len(url)) y
    , url 
    from f2 
) y 
on y.y = x.x
```

Comment: This looks great. I will play around with this. Thank you.